Negative covariance matrix in RI CLPM (lavaan)
I am currently struggling to solve the problem of negative covariance regarding the latent variables with respect to the random intercepts in my RI CLPM model, which I calculate via lavaan.
Here is my model code
RICLPM <- '
  # Create between components (random intercepts)
  RI_x =~ 1*x_1 + 1*x_2 + 1*x_3
  RI_y =~ 1*y_1 + 1*y_2 + 1*y_3
  
  # Create within-person centered variables
  w_x_1 =~ 1*x_1
  w_x_2 =~ 1*x_2
  w_x_3 =~ 1*x_3
  w_y_1 =~ 1*y_1
  w_y_2 =~ 1*y_2
  w_y_3 =~ 1*y_3

  # Estimate lagged effects between within-person centered variables
  w_x_2 ~ w_x_1
  w_x_3 ~ w_x_2
  w_y_2 ~ w_y_1
  w_y_3 ~ w_y_2

  # Estimate cross-lagged effects between within-person centered variables
  w_y_2 ~ w_x_1
  w_y_3 ~ w_x_2
  w_x_2 ~ w_y_1
  w_x_3 ~ w_y_2

  # Regress observed variables on z (constant)
  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ~ z
  y_1 + y_2 + y_3 ~ z

  # Estimate variances and covariances of random intercepts
  RI_x ~~ RI_x
  RI_y ~~ RI_y
  RI_x ~~ RI_y

  # Estimate (residual) variances of within-person centered variables
  w_x_1 ~~ w_x_1
  w_y_1 ~~ w_y_1
  w_x_2 ~~ w_x_2
  w_y_2 ~~ w_y_2
  w_x_3 ~~ w_x_3
  w_y_3 ~~ w_y_3

  # Estimate residual covariances between within-person centered variables at the same time points
  w_x_1 ~~ w_y_1
  w_x_2 ~~ w_y_2
  w_x_3 ~~ w_y_3

  # Estimate residual variances for within-person centered variables
  w_x_2 ~ u2*1
  w_y_2 ~ v2*1
  w_x_3 ~ u3*1
  w_y_3 ~ v3*1
'

fit <- lavaan::sem(RICLPM, data = final_data, missing = 'ML', meanstructure = TRUE, int.ov.free = TRUE)

I receive the following warning:

> fit <- lavaan::sem(RICLPM, data = data, missing = 'ML', meanstructure = TRUE, int.ov.free = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  :
  lavaan WARNING: 259 cases were deleted due to missing values in 
          exogenous variable(s), while fixed.x = TRUE.
2: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.
3: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables
                is not positive definite;
                use lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv") to investigate.

And here is my covariance matrix:
> lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv")
                    RI_x RI_y w___1 w___2 w___3 w____1 w____2 w____3
RI_x             0.306                                                              
RI_y                 0.168  0.269                                                       
w_x_1           -0.056 -0.002    0.347                                              
w_x_2           -0.023 -0.006    0.137    0.185                                     
w_x_3           -0.002 -0.001    0.012    0.039   0.079                             
w_y_1           -0.030 -0.029    0.153    0.085   0.011     0.210                   
w_y_2           -0.011 -0.008    0.061    0.272   0.029     0.068     0.158         
w_y_3           -0.001  0.000    0.006    0.016   0.139     0.005     0.013    0.115

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be solved?
Thanks a lot!

I would start by ensuring the model is identified. Also, what is the sample size (how many subjects do you have) ?

Given:

WARNING: 259 cases were deleted due to missing values

and

The information matrix could not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not identified.

I would start there. These two issues can jointly affect the estimation. By default lavaan uses casewise deletion for handling missing data. I would start by choosing Full Information Maximum Likelihood (FIML), by using the missing = FIML in the call to sem(). If warnings persist regarding identification, then ensure sufficient Degrees of Freedom using the formula df = n_obs - n_params, where n_obs is the number of observed variances and covariances, and n_params is the number of estimated parameters.
